# At which point did God try to destroy the Israelites whilst they were in Egypt as alluded in Ezekiel 20:8?

Tags: exodus, numbers, moses, ezekiel

Ezekiel 20:8 NIV

8 “‘But they rebelled against me and would not listen to me; they did not get rid of the vile images they had set their eyes on, nor did they forsake the idols of Egypt. ***So I said I would pour out my wrath on them and spend my anger against them in Egypt***

I have not found any record of God trying to destroy the Israelites whilst they were still in Egypt but all the rebellions were after they had left that country as stated below

1. At Pi Hahiroth(Exodus 14)
2. At Marah(Exodus 15)
3. Desert of Sin(Exodus 16)
4. At Massah(Exodus 17)
5. The golden calf(Exodus 32)
6. At Taberah(Numbers 11)
7. At Meribah(Numbers 20)

These are some of the incidents were Israel rebelled against God and God wanted to destroy them,but all of them took place outside Egypt

At which point did God try to destroy Israel in Egypt

Comment: As Yoda said, “there is no try”, only do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eze 20:8 is probably referring to the incident in Ex 32 -

> **7** Then the LORD said to Moses, “Go down at once, for your people, whom you brought up out of the land of Egypt, have corrupted
> themselves. **8** How quickly they have turned aside from the way that
> I commanded them! They have made for themselves a molten calf and have
> bowed down to it. They have sacrificed to it and said, ‘These, O
> Israel, are your gods, who brought you up out of the land of Egypt.’ ”
>
> **9** The LORD also said to Moses, “I have seen this people, and they are indeed a stiff-necked people. **10** Now leave Me alone, **so that
> My anger may burn against them and consume them**. Then I will make
> you into a great nation.”

A very similar incident occurred in Num 14:11-20 when God intended to destroy all the Israelites.  Note the comments of Ellicott -

> **(8) The land of Egypt**.—Of this idolatrous rebellion, and of this threat of the Divine anger while they were still in Egypt, as already
> said, we have no specific record. But they had the same disposition
> then as they had afterwards; and, even without such a charge, we could
> infer the probability of their idolatry. It is possible that the
> prophet may have had in mind such incidents as are related in Numbers
> 14:11-20, happening while the Israelites were still in the
> neighbourhood of Egypt, and when the report of them would speedily
> have reached Egyptian ears. It is by no means necessary to suppose
> that in this broad and general review of the teachings of history each
> incident is kept in its strict chronological place.

Answer (score 0):

Ezekiel 20:8 is where this history is described. It isn't described elsewhere. Why wont you accept Ezekiel as the record? Are you looking for a different record, like a secondary witness? Most of the events in Exodus don't have a secondary witness either, so why impose the secondary witness requirement to Ezekiel but not Exodus?